# Equal queens in every aspect

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

It is asked that you

> place $12$ queens on a $5$x$5$ chess board so that every queen can *see* the same number of empty squares.
>
> For the purposes of this puzzle, **a queen can *see* any square on the same rank, file, or diagonal, regardless of any pieces or empty squares in between**.

For example:

[image]

In this example, every queen can count $7$ empty squares which they can see.

The question is

> How can you **place $\mathbf{12}$ queens so that each queen sees exactly** $\mathbf{6}$ **empty squares**?

and

> Where to **put $\mathbf{12}$ queens so that each queen sees exactly** $\mathbf{5}$ **empty squares**?

and lastly,

> How to **place only** $\mathbf{8}$ **queens so that each queen sees exactly** $\mathbf{10}$ **empty squares**?

Comment: It may be quite clear, but I can only count 6 legal moves per queen in your example... Could you explain a bit more what is a movable square?

Comment: The queens in the middle of tops and sides; how can they move to 7 empty aquares?  I only count 5, unless they can jump over existing queens.

Comment: @Untitpoi it is not legal move count, it is the count where they could originally move if all squares were empty except the queen herself.

Comment: @APrough please "count the empty square in all direction where queen could move if these squares were all empty."

Comment: @Untitpoi yes I may not able to put it into the words clearly. be my guest to fix texting.

Comment: In chess, moving through other pieces is expressly forbidden, and counting empty squares that can be reached while imagining some other squares being empty as well feels needlessly confusing, so maybe use another word altogether, like "A queen can **see** any square on the same rank, file, or diagonal, regardless of any pieces in between", and work from there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For **12** queens and count **5** (same as 
[Saeïdryl's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68387/150))

[image]

For **12** queens and count **6** either of the below

[image]
[image]

For **8** queens and count **10**

[image]

A brute force search confirms that these are the only solutions disregarding trivial rotations and reflections. As a bonus here is the only other solution for **12** queens and count **7** other than the one given in the question.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Partial answer
If I understand correctly,
For $12$ queens to make the count to $5$

> [image]

Bonus :
For $8$ queens to make the count to $9$ (not in the question)

> [image]

Comment: You're bonus is 9 and 9, not 12 and 9

Comment: Actually, I think it's 8 and 9, but I can't edit it bc need more than 6 characters.

Comment: I really can't count sorry :D